# I can no longer edit rdp files

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, editing

When I right click on rdp files, I no longer have the "edit" option.
The only way to modify the rdp file is to edit it with notepad which is not very convenient.

How can I fixe this please ? 
I need this "edit" option when I right click on rdp files.

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the output from `reg query "HKCR\RDP.File" /s` you should see _two_ lines `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RDP.File\shell\Edit\command` and `(Default)    REG_SZ    mstsc.exe -edit "%1"`.

Comment: I see them but I don't have the edit option though